# Displaying an image from base64 encoded MongoDB field in flask

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, base64, jinja2

I'm storing an image in MongoDB in the following way and attempting to display the image, however I am having issues doing this. I'm sure this is down to the encoding.

My display on the page using `jinja2`

```
<a src="image/png:base64, {{record.my_image | b64d}}">
```

`b64d` is a custom filter to decode the string field.

```
from base64 import b64decode as b64decode
app.jinja_env.filters['b64d'] = lambda u: b64decode(u)
```

Fields in Mongo look like:

```
"my_image": "/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEASABIAAD/2wBDAAYEBQYFBAYGBQYHBwYIChAKCgkJChQODwwQFxQYGBcUFhYaHSUfGhsjHBYWICwgIyYnKSopGR8tMC0oMCUoKSj/2wB..."
```

I convert the image in the following way, where url is the url of the image.

```
def ImgURL(url):
    img = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
    encoded_string = base64.b64encode(img)
    return encoded_string
```

However when I try and run the page in flask, I get the following error message:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x89 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: Isn't it the browser's responsibility to decode the b64 data?  That's why you specify the encoding in the `src` tag.

Comment: @mgilson I did try without the filter, but I don't see anything rendered on the screen.

Answer (score 2):

Filter :

```
    from base64 import b64encode

app.jinja_env.filters['b64d'] = lambda u: b64encode(u).decode()
```

Template :

```
<img src="data:;base64,{{ record.my_image.thumbnail.read()|b64d }}">
```

Assume, my image use ImageField of mongoengine

Others need use my_image.read() // not thumbnail